# Having trouble linking /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, macos

I have been trying to figure out how to solve this error for hours and have not found a solution. I have been to almost every stack overflow thread that references this question, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get rid of this problem.

> Error:
>
> Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
>
> Full Stack Trace:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 3296, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
>       engine = create_engine('mysql://root:550275Dev?@localhost:3306/stock_prices/stock_prices')
>   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/**init**.py",
>   line 435, in create_engine
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py",
>   line 87, in create
>       dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
>       return **import**("MySQLdb")   File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py",
>   line 21, in do_import
>       module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       from . import _mysql   File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py",
>   line 21, in do_import
>       module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs) ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
>   Reason: image not found

System:

macos Moave 10.14.5

Solutions that I have attempted:

Attempt 1:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
```

Error:

> ln: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib: Operation not permitted

Attempt 2:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
```

Error:

> ln: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib: File exists

There have been other solutions, but maybe I'm just not understanding them correctly.

I simply want MySQldb/mysqlclient to work with python's mysqlalchemy library. I'm specifically trying to use the create_engine fn.

Comment: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: You cannot create anything under /usr because it is protected by SIP, so the command you tried returned error. The right place to link is under /usr/local/lib/ but you tried and it shows that it already exists there. Please check if it is valid or a dead/wrong softlink, check it with ls -l /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib and see if it the existing softlink is correctly pointing to a valid file, or post the ls result here. Exporting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH only works for systems where SIP is disabled, I don't think it will help this situation where SIP is enabled.